# Add 48 hours to a timestamp in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, timestamp

I have a CSV file that has a timestamp in DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM 24-hour format that I'm needing to add 48 hours to and return in Month DD, YYYY HH:MM format in Powershell.

So 13.03.2013 23:12 would return as March 15, 2013 23:12, or 14.03.2013 10:00 would return as March 16, 2013 10:00.

I've tried using

`$newDate = [DateTime]::$_.Timestamp.AddHours(48)`

But Powershell keeps telling me that - ***"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date format matches your culture settings then you should be able to parse the date string using Get-Date:

```
$date = Get-Date '13.03.2013 23:12'
```

If it doesn't, you'll need to use the ParseExact method:

```
$date = [DateTime]::ParseExact('13.03.2013 23:12','dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',$null)
```

Now, you can add 48 hours to it and then format it as you wanted to:

```
$date.AddHours(48).ToString('dd, yyyy HH:mm')
```

---

*Updated from @gjettison comment*

The timestamp was not in US format, I had to play around with the culture a little the following accomplishes what I was looking for

```
$stampCulture = [Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-GB")   
$timeStamp = [datetime]::Parse($_.Timestamp, $stampCulture)   
$expire = $timeStamp.AddHours(48).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:MM")
```

Comment: thank you for the ideas. As the timestamp was not in US format, I had to play around with the culture a little the following accomplishes what I was looking for. You get the correct answer for pointing me in the culture direction! `$stampCulture = [Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-GB")
                    $timeStamp = [datetime]::Parse($_.Timestamp, $stampCulture)
                    $expire = $timeStamp.AddHours(48).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:MM")`

Answer (score 1):

To parse your date you can use :

```
$a = [datetime]::parse("13.03.2013 23:12")
```

so the following works :

```
$b = $a.AddHours(48)
```

You can format it using :

```
$b.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:MM:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `$_.Timestamp` before adding the hours as the message is suggesting its null.

You could use TryParse if there is a possibility of the value not containing a date.

```
[string]$originalString = "25.12.2013 18:00"
[DateTime]$originalDate = Get-Date

if ([DateTime]::TryParse($originalString,  [ref]$originalDate))
{

    Write-Host "got date: $originalDate" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "plus 48 hours:" $originalDate.AddHours(48) -ForegroundColor Green
}
else
{
    Write-Host "error" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```